# How to write MongoDB query statement for a specific requirement?

Tags: mongodb

Here is the MongoDB document format:

```
{
    '_id':...,
    'user_id':...,
    'user_info':...,
    ...
}
```

The `user_info`'s value is a number or a string, I'd like to combine all the `user_info`'s value into an array as the key 'user_info' 's value in the query result, like here:

```
{ 'user_id': ..., 'user_info': [ ..., ...] }
```

How to write the query statement to query data like this?

Comment: the 'user_id' may the same, but 'user_id' with 'user_info' is a kind of primary key in SQL, so I would like to make the `user_id` output unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$in`

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```
db.users.find({'user_info': {$in: [1, "a"]}})
```

Here you can read about it [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm still confused, may be my description is not clearly. the `user_id` may be the same, but my result need the `user_id` to be unique.

Comment: Try it:   
`db.users.aggregate([{$match: {'user_info': {$in: [1, "a"]}}}, {$group:{_id: "$user_id", user_infos: {$addToSet: "$user_info"}}}])`